# Microsoft Academic Research Co-author graph-Like Component

Tags: silverlight, flash, visualization, graph-visualization

I Want to use a component like the VisualExploer in [microsoft Academic Page](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/VisualExplorer#196415&1112639)

I want to use a silverlight, flash or javascript component in a similar way.

I would be so grateful if you provide me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight has something that is kind of similar that might do the trick for you. It's called PivotViewer: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/pivotviewer/

Here's a demo of what it looks like:

http://www.thomaswinzer.com/archivecat/